# Raster file not overlaying to vector layer

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system

I'm pretty new to GIS and following a tutorial using shape files from Ithaca, NY. I've been able load a number of vector files easily enough but when I add in the .dem raster file it keeps being placed a good distance to the north. I think this issue might be related to a mismatch in Coordinate Reference Systems.

My raster comes from here - https://cugir.library.cornell.edu/catalog/cugir-008186

and I'm using parcel shapefile  from -https://cugir.library.cornell.edu/catalog/cugir-007938

Theoretically the raster should overlay onto the eastern portion of the parcels.

I'm using QGIS Coruna and Postgres10 w/ pgadmin4.

Comment: Do you have "On the fly" crs transformation turned on?

Comment: From what I understand OTF is enabled by default. I'm not certain I can find OTF to enable/disable in QGIS Coruna.

Comment: That's correct, OTF is on by default (since the switch from QGIS 2 to 3). Probably one of your layers has the wrong CRS set. Add a basemap to your project. Compare each of the two layers to the basemap, and see which one is in the wrong location. Then the real work begins: figuring out what CRS it's supposed to have. Check out this answer for help with that: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/339352/81764